# Como verificar se os arquivos "DLL" foi registrado com sucesso

Tags: c#, dll

Preciso verificar se o processo foi executado com sucesso, no caso as extensões que ele vai tentar registrar são:

- .DLL
- .OCX

O Código que estou usando pra registrar é este:

```
string pathcli = copiar + nomedofonte;

if (!nomedofonte.Contains(".exe") ||!nomedofonte.Contains(".EXE"))
{                        
    Process proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = Registrador,
            Arguments = "/s"+pathcli,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
         }
     };

    proc.Start();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Como que irei verificar se os arquivos daquela extensão foram registrado com sucesso?

Comment: Só de curiosidade, pra que alguém precisa de DLL registrada nos OSes modernos, em vez de simplesmente carregar? Outra coisa. e se a extensão for uma das variantes como `.Exe`, ou `.eXe`, por eXEmplo? Não seria o caso de comparar _case insensitive_?

Comment: Não, Pois é um sistema interno da empresa, onde precisa justamente registrar as DLL pra outro sistema poder entender e rodar, o .EXE eu usei a verificação pra ignorar essas extensão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode inspecionar o registro do Windows para ver se a `DLL` ou `OCX` está registrado. O node **CLSID** tem as chaves registradas:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`

Porém para isso você precisa saber o `Guid`, e provavelmente você não sabe. Então a solução é ler as sub-chaves do **CLSID** e procurar pelo nome da `DLL` ou `OCX`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
bool VerificarRegistro(string nomeDLL)
{
    bool achou = false;
    RegistryKey clsid = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID");
    string[] ClsIDs = clsid.GetSubKeyNames();
    string subkey = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ClsIDs.Length; i++)
    {
        subkey = ClsIDs[i];
        if (subkey.Substring(0, 1) != "{") continue;
        RegistryKey cls = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID\\" + subkey + "\\InprocServer32");
        if (cls == null) continue;
        string x = cls.GetValue("", "").ToString();
        if (x.IndexOf(nomeDLL) >= 0)
        {
            achou = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return achou;
}
```

Comment: Esta quase la, mas me deu uma luz, muito obrigado.